# AFreeChart OHLCDataset: how to remove spaces where no data at date axis?

Tags: java, android, charts, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

There are no data at 9th-10th march, is it possible to remove space between this period?

[image: OHLC chart]

Comment: is the data weekend data? or just a gap in your data set?

Comment: yes, it is weeken data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is weekend data that produces the gaps you can do something like this

```
SegmentedTimeline timeline = SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline();
((DateAxis) chart.getXYPlot().getDomainAxis()).setTimeline(timeline);
```

or

```
final OHLCDataset dataset = new DefaultOHLCDataset("Series1", ohlc);
SegmentedTimeline timeline = SegmentedTimeline.newMondayThroughFridayTimeline();
chart = ChartFactory.createHighLowChart(this.getTitle(),xLabel, yLabel,dataset,timeline, false);
```

If it is not the weekend then you will have to be a little more clever with the `SegmentedTimeline` api

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SegmentedTimeline.html